401 unauthorized error, Jib is unable to authenticate with the Docker registry repository
I am fairly new to jib gradle plugin and have been trying to push my image to docker hub using jib gradle plugin in a jenkins pipeline but i keep getting the 401 unauthorized error.
I followed the instructions in  to set the pass credential helper and use it to store my credentials and also added my credentials in jenkins but i still get the error below when deploying to dockerhub with jib. I have tried logging in to dockerhub locally and the credentials i am using work but they fail in the pipeline.
Jenkins logs
Stage Logs (Deploy to DockerHub with Jib)
 Shell Script -- echo "${DOCKER_PASSWORD}" | docker login -u "${DOCKER_USERNAME}" --password-stdin ./gradlew jib -Djib.to.auth.username="${DOCKER_USERNAME}" -Djib.to.auth.password="${DOCKER_PASSWORD}" -Djib.to.image=jedfavour/jenkins-docker-project:latest --stacktrace (self time 16s)
eTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:74)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:331)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:318)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.lambda$execute$0(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:314)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.CurrentBuildOperationRef.with(CurrentBuildOperationRef.java:80)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:314)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:303)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:463)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:380)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor.process(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:116)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.executeWithServices(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:138)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:51)
    at org.gradle.execution.BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkerExecutor$ExecuteTasks.call(BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkerExecutor.java:54)
    at org.gradle.execution.BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkerExecutor$ExecuteTasks.call(BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkerExecutor.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.execution.BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkerExecutor.execute(BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkerExecutor.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.lambda$executeTasks$10(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:313)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:266)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$tryTransition$8(StateTransitionController.java:177)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.tryTransition(StateTransitionController.java:177)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.executeTasks(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:304)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildWorkGraphController$DefaultBuildWorkGraph.runWork(DefaultBuildWorkGraphController.java:220)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:264)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:128)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultBuildController.doRun(DefaultBuildController.java:181)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultBuildController.access$000(DefaultBuildController.java:50)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultBuildController$BuildOpRunnable.lambda$run$0(DefaultBuildController.java:198)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.CurrentBuildOperationRef.with(CurrentBuildOperationRef.java:80)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultBuildController$BuildOpRunnable.run(DefaultBuildController.java:198)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47)
Caused by: com.google.cloud.tools.jib.plugins.common.BuildStepsExecutionException: Build image failed, perhaps you should make sure your credentials for 'registry-1.docker.io/jedfavour/jenkins-docker-project' are set up correctly. See https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/blob/master/docs/faq.md#what-should-i-do-when-the-registry-responds-with-unauthorized for help
    at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.plugins.common.JibBuildRunner.handleRegistryUnauthorizedException(JibBuildRunner.java:183)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.plugins.common.JibBuildRunner.runBuild(JibBuildRunner.java:263)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.gradle.BuildImageTask.buildImage(BuildImageTask.java:122)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:125)
    ... 148 more
Caused by: com.google.cloud.tools.jib.api.RegistryUnauthorizedException: Unauthorized for registry-1.docker.io/jedfavour/jenkins-docker-project
    at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.plugins.common.JibBuildRunner.runBuild(JibBuildRunner.java:265)
    ... 153 more
Caused by: com.google.cloud.tools.jib.http.ResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
GET https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:jedfavour/jenkins-docker-project:pull,push
{"details":"incorrect username or password"}

    at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.http.FailoverHttpClient.call(FailoverHttpClient.java:355)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.http.FailoverHttpClient.call(FailoverHttpClient.java:266)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.registry.RegistryAuthenticator.authenticate(RegistryAuthenticator.java:283)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.registry.RegistryAuthenticator.authenticate(RegistryAuthenticator.java:257)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.registry.RegistryAuthenticator.authenticatePush(RegistryAuthenticator.java:190)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.registry.RegistryClient.doBearerAuth(RegistryClient.java:336)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.registry.RegistryClient.doBearerAuth(RegistryClient.java:326)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.registry.RegistryClient.doPushBearerAuth(RegistryClient.java:308)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.builder.steps.AuthenticatePushStep.call(AuthenticatePushStep.java:66)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.builder.steps.AuthenticatePushStep.call(AuthenticatePushStep.java:35)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:131)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:74)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:82)
Caused by: com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
GET https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:jedfavour/jenkins-docker-project:pull,push
{"details":"incorrect username or password"}

    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException$Builder.build(HttpResponseException.java:293)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1118)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.http.FailoverHttpClient.call(FailoverHttpClient.java:349)
    ... 12 more


Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.

BUILD FAILED in 11s
3 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 2 up-to-date

Build.gradle
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
    id 'jacoco'
    id 'com.google.cloud.tools.jib' version '3.3.1'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
        targetCompatibility = '17'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
test {
  finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
}
jib {
  from {
    image = 'openjdk:alpine'
  }
  to {
    image = 'jedfavour/jenkins-docker-project'
    credHelper = 'pass'
    tags = [version, 'latest']
  }}


Jenkinsfile
  stage("Clone project") {
    git branch: 'main', url: 'https://github.com/jed212/Jenkins-ci-cd.git'
  }

  stage("Build project with test execution") {
    sh "./gradlew build"
  }
  
  stage("Deploy to DockerHub with Jib") {
    parallel([
        docker: {
            withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'DOCKER_CRED', usernameVariable: 'DOCKER_USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'DOCKER_PASSWORD')]) {
                sh '''
                echo "${DOCKER_PASSWORD}" | docker login -u "${DOCKER_USERNAME}" --password-stdin
                ./gradlew jib -Djib.to.auth.username="${DOCKER_USERNAME}" -Djib.to.auth.password="${DOCKER_PASSWORD}" -Djib.to.image=jedfavour/jenkins-docker-project:latest --stacktrace
                '''
            }
        },
    ])
  }

  jacoco(
    execPattern: '**/*.exec',
    sourcePattern: 'src/main/java',
    exclusionPattern: 'src/test*'
  )
}


I am familiar with this particular error response from Docker Hub: "details":"incorrect username or password"} It is when you provided a wrong or non-working username or password to Docker Hub.
